# Disabling a key in Ubuntu 18.04.2 which doesn't show in keyboard panel

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard-shortcuts

I have a problem that when I'm pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> (both right and left) Ubuntu changes the language...
I want to disable the shortcut of changing a language in my Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS , but I don't see it in the shortcuts panel...
I only see <kbd>super</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> (in the picture 'Switch to next input source') ...

[image: keyboard shortcuts in ubuntu]

Answer (score 0):

Since this is actually performed by [iBus](https://github.com/ibus/ibus/wiki/ReadMe), suggest you check to make sure ibus-daemon is running. If it is not, run ibus-daemon to start ibus daemon:

```
 $ ps -ef | grep ibus
 $ /usr/bin/ibus-daemon --xim &
```

After ibus-daemon is invoked, Run **ibus-setup** to change your preference to obviate <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd> from changing your input language.